# Memory error with large dataset (Python,NIST19)

Tags: python, memory, dataset

I have a problem when I try to train a large dataset, NIST19 in binary format. It is 13gb and the script I use to train it output Memory Error after few minutes.

Here is the script:

```
#python train.py --dataset data/NIST19.csv --model models/svm.cpickle

from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from hog import HOG
import dataset
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required = True,
    help = "path to the dataset file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required = True,
    help = "path to where the model will be stored")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
(digits, target) = dataset.load_digits(args["dataset"])
data = []

hog = HOG(orientations = 18, pixelsPerCell = (10, 10),
    cellsPerBlock = (1, 1), transform = True)

for image in digits:
    image = dataset.deskew(image, 20)
    image = dataset.center_extent(image, (20, 20))
    hist = hog.describe(image)
    data.append(hist)

model = LinearSVC(random_state = 42)
model.fit(data, target)
joblib.dump(model, args["model"])
```

You can find the [dataset here](http://seeb0h.github.io/learning/preprocess-sd19-dataset-for-digits-learning/) if you want to try.
It's a .txt binary dataset which I converted in .csv